# Where would main be implemented in order for the program to execute in this code?

Tags: java, swing, compiler-errors

So I am having a difficult time trying to wrap my head around where main should be in order for the code to compile and execute. I know that Java needs one main method. I have put it in certain areas but it then explains that some classes are not defined. I tried doing more than what the professor asked for and maybe it wasn't the best idea but understanding this would be appreciated. Thank you. I forgot to explain that the purpose of the program is to take user input and have the numerical value multiplied by itself. I tried accomplishing this but after learning C++, parsing has me a little confused as well.

```
 /**
  * 
  *@author ngc5043
  *@version 1.0 
  */

 import javax.swing.*;
 import java.awt.event.*;

 public class Nicolas_Carabajal_Assignment3 extends JFrame
 {
      private JPanel panel;
      private JLabel messageLabel;
      private JTextField ExTextField;
      private JButton calcButton;
      private final int WINODW_WIDTH = 310;
      private final int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 100;

  public Nicolas_Carabajal_Assignment3(int WINDOW_WIDTH)
  {
    setTitle("Expressions Window");
    setSize(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    buildPanel();
    add(panel);
    setVisible(true);
  }

  private void buildPanel()
  {
       messageLabel = new JLabel("Please Enter a Number");
       ExTextField = new JTextField(10);
       calcButton = new JButton("Calculate");
       calcButton.addActionListener(new CalcButtonListener());
       panel = new JPanel();
       panel.add(messageLabel);
       panel.add(ExTextField);
       panel.add(calcButton);
   }

   private class CalcButtonListener implements ActionListener
  {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
       {
           String inputString;
          double answerOne;
           inputString = ExTextField.getText();
           answerOne = Double.parseDouble(inputString)* inputString;
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Your Answer Is" + answerOne);                
       }

   }

   }
```

Comment: Please don't update the code in your question to incorporate code from answers. It makes your question confusing to read for future viewers. If you have additional problems, please use comments to ask for clarification or ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Place you main method inside your `Nicolas_Carabajal_Assignment3` class. Create a new instance of that class in the main method and you should see your JFrame appear assuming all of your other code is correct.

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple, just add it to the beginning of your code right before the constructor.

```
public class Nicolas_Carabajal_Assignment3 extends JFrame {
  private JPanel panel;
  private JLabel messageLabel;
  private JTextField ExTextField;
  private JButton calcButton;
  private final int WINODW_WIDTH = 310;
  private final int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 100;

  public static void main(String[] args){
      Nicolas_Carabajal_Assignment3 main = new Nicolas_Carabajal_Assignment3(SIZE_OF_WINDOW);
      main.buildPanel();
  } 
  ...
```

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Thank you for the help. I added the code where you told me it should go. I have been staring at this thing and it is probably very simple but now it says there is an error with this.

Nicolas_Carabajal_Assignment3.java:25: error: <identifier> expected
      public Nicolas_Carabajal_Assignment3(WINDOW_WIDTH)

Comment: Sorry this is a little late, but all you have to do is set your WINDOW_WIDTH and your WINDOW_HIGHT to public.